# rust compiler omit simple structure when generating llvm-ir

Tags: rust, llvm

I want to gather some layout information of a struct from llvm-ir, however, some simple structure may be omitted by rustc when generating llvm-ir.

For examle:

```rust
// test.rs
pub struct A {
    id: i32,
    data: i64
}
```

when generates llvm-ir:

```bash
rustc --emit=llvm-ir test.rs // got test.ll
```

No structure information can be found in `test.ll`, while I expect `%A = type { i32, [1 x i32], i64 }` or something similar.

Is there any way avoid rustc omit these information?

By the way, how can I know whether a field in llvm-ir is a padding or actual variables, if given the source code.

I did not find much useful information about this problem...

Comment: No there is not. Hook the Rust compiler at earlier stage, e.g. MIR.